# can zsh autocomplete to its autosuggestion?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I type ssh, it auto suggest to the last host I've ssh'd into.

```
ssh <AUTOSUGGESTED HOST>
```

Is there a way so that when I type "tab" it just autocompletes to the autosuggested option?